# Serialization Issue in Pytest/xdist

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist

```
Replacing crashed worker gw0
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 191, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 246, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 257, in pytest_collection
INTERNALERROR>     return session.perform_collect()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 453, in perform_collect
INTERNALERROR>     self.config.pluginmanager.check_pending()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 277, in check_pending
INTERNALERROR>     % (name, hookimpl.plugin),
INTERNALERROR> pluggy.manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_logwarning' in plugin <__channelexec__.WorkerInteractor object at 0x106b59490>
gw3 C / gw1 [3] / gw2 C[gw1] node down: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/execnet/gateway_base.py", line 1383, in _save
    dispatch = self._dispatch[tp]
```

### KeyError:

```
raise DumpError("can't serialize %s" % (tp,))
execnet.gateway_base.DumpError: can't serialize <enum 'ExitCode'>
```

--
I am running into this issue when running UI test in parallel. I want to run test cases in 3 chrome driver in parllel.
Here is what i did:

```
 pytest "filenamepath" --headless=false --html  TestReport.html -n 3
```

I am running into above error. Would appreciate if anyone has come across same issue and resolved it.

Comment: See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/487. One comment says: "I had this problem with pytest-xdist 1.26.1 and can confirm that it is fixed with 1.31.0."